# Open a new MacVim window with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, macvim

I can open a new iTerm window like this:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    create window with default profile
end tell
```

How do I do the same but with MacVim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open a new window in **MacVim**, you can use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "MacVim"
    activate
    delay 1
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "n" using command down
end tell
```

- Note that the *value* of the `delay` *command* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *command(s)* as appropriate.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: This seems to bring up the existing MacVim window, I was hoping it would create a brand new window instead (same as right click on MacVim icon in the dock and then clicking New Window does). Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: @zoran119, I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/5400816

```
tell application "System Events"
    set currProcs to (name of processes)
    set MacVimRunning to (currProcs contains "MacVim")
    if not MacVimRunning then
        tell application "MacVim" to activate
    end if
    tell process "MacVim"
        click menu item "New Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        set visible to true
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me.  It uses the `mvim` utility that comes with MacVim to do the hard work.  The AppleScript can be simpler and doesn't need special handling if MacVim is already open:

```
do shell script "cd; {path_to}/mvim &> /dev/null &"
```

Comment: Try to explain why it worked and why it was better for you